# Oracle forms: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, tnsnames

I have oracle Enterprise edition and oracle forms installed on my computer, when i connect to my database from sqlplus and sqldevelopper, it connects without errors, but when i try to connect from oracle forms, it gives me this error:

```
ORA-12154:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I have looked online and i read somewhere that it might be because i have more than one oracle client installed on my computer, and the sqlplus uses the right file and oracle forms uses the one that is not right, and i think that is my case, because i have two of the **tnsnames.ora** file :
in here:

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
```

and in here:

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\NETWORK\ADMIN\SAMPLE
```

here is the content of the first tnsnames.ora file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = BOUHDID.Home)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

if it's the case, how can i fix this?

Comment: Is your `oracleforms` pointing to C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora?

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://pitss.com/us/2014/02/26/how-to-map-tnsnames-ora-to-a-different-location-for-forms-and-reports/)?

Comment: @NicholasV. How do i know whereis "oracleforms" pointing to?

Comment: Personally I don't use Oracleforms, so I'm not sure. I know in SQLDeveloper, the TNSNames is set in **Tools > Preferences > Database > Advanced**. Perhaps Oracleforms has a similar setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing these steps:

1. uninstalled Oracle froms and reports.
2. uninstalled Oracle dababase with universal installer.
3. Deleted all the registries and services associated with oracle.
4. Reinstalled Oracle database.
5. Reinstalled oracle forms & reports.
6. copied from my tnsnames.ora file located in

`C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN` to the tnsnames.ora file located in `C:\orant\NET80\ADMIN` 
 this part:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = BOUHDID)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variabele.
This alawys points to the tnsnames.ora directory. And all oracle products look at this variabele.

So you just have to set `TNS_ADMIN` to:

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
```

Comment: I actually did that, but it kept giving me the same error! so i uninstalled everything, and reinstalled it again

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Oracle_Home variable config, please check if TNS entry is present in the domains folder created while installing oracle forms & reports.
Example: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\tnsnames.ora